# How to check and replace a sequence of characters in a String?

Tags: java

Here what the program is expectiong as the output: 
if originalString = "CATCATICATAMCATCATGREATCATCAT";
Output should be "I AM GREAT".
The code must find the sequence of characters (CAT in this case), and remove them. Plus, the resulting String must have spaces in between words.

```
        String origString = remixString.replace("CAT", "");
```

I figured out I have to use String.replace, But what could be the logic for finding out if its not cat and producing the resulting string with spaces in between the words.

Comment: Please read up about `replaceAll()` and `trim()`

Comment: try  this one as well -  Stream.of(remixString).map(C-> C.replaceAll("(CAT)+", " ").trim()).forEach(c->System.out.println(c));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you probably want to use the `replaceAll` method instead, to make sure you replace all occurrences of "CAT" within the String.  Then, you want to introduce spaces, so instead of an empty String, replace "CAT" with " " (space).

As pointed out by the comment below, there might be multiple spaces between words - so we use a regular expression to replace multiple instances of "CAT" with a single space.  The '+' symbol means "one or more",.

Finally, trim the String to get rid of leading and trailing white space.

`remixString.replaceAll("(CAT)+", " ").trim()`

Comment: I think there can be multiple `CAT`s in between words too. so that will lead to multiple spaces in between words

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll` which accepts a regular expression:

```
String remixString = "CATCATICATAMCATCATGREATCATCAT";
String origString = remixString.replaceAll("(CAT)+", " ").trim();
```

Note: the naming of `replace` and `replaceAll` is very confusing. They both replace all instances of the matching string; the difference is that `replace` takes a literal text as an argument, while `replaceAll` takes a regular expression.

Comment: You can use stream api also -   Stream.of(remixString).map(C-> C.replaceAll("(CAT)+", " ").trim()).forEach(c->System.out.println(c));

Comment: Yes, you can use streams, but you probably shouldn't.  Why create a stream for a single value and make the code that much harder to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
String result = remixString.replaceAll("(CAT){1,}", " ");
```